# latest gearman on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, gearman

Is it possible to install gearman 1.1.12 on Ubuntu 12.04 without compiling it manually? Doing an `add-apt-repository ppa:gearman-developers/ppa` before doing an `apt-get install` still installs the old version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works... I just need to do an `apt-get upgrade`.